# Cassandra connections rebalancing between seeds after a maintenance

Tags: java, cassandra

When restarting one Cassandra seed node, all its client connection are rebalance to other nodes as expected. However, when the node is up again the incoming connection are not staying to the previous level. It causes a ~10% performance impact since the other nodes are slightly more used. Restarting the client applications solve the issue.

**Is it possible to have an automatic client rebalancing without a restart of the clients after some time, e.g. 1h?**

I am using 4 seeds node on my application with the latest Java driver `com.datastax.oss:java-driver-bom:4.15.0` and `Cassandra 4.0.7`. Load balancing policy used is `DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy`.

Here is an example of the restart of one node. in graph.
[image: Restart of one node without re-balancing]

Comment: This looks like a steady state after the restart, do clients close and (re-)open their connections by themself as part of the application logic?

Comment: it is fully managed by the Cassandra client.
It is indeed a steady state but I would like to have something more balanced between all seed nodes. 
My question is about is there such possibility on the Cassandra client to recreate a connection to another node even if fully healthy nodes.

Comment: This should work out of the box, if connections are not uninterrupted in use f.e. for streaming queries. See https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/load_balancing/ for details.

Comment: it is not reconnecting once connected to another node.
Let say the client1 is connected to seed 1 & 3, if seed1 is restarting, client1 will connect to seed 2 (& 3). Once seed 1 is back, it won't reconnect to seed1 and release seed2 connection.

Comment: The client becomes a member of the cluster that is why a seed node connection is needed. It should connect and query the node that contains the data according to the topology - except configured otherwise. Even if querying the wrong node, that node will act as a proxy and connect to the node holding the data. Is your data well balanced?

Comment: data is present on all nodes, 5 nodes setup with 5 replica

Comment: If data is present on all nodes it depends on the load balancing policy configured. I would expect indeed round-robin over all nodes in that case. Which driver version are you using and how did you configure the topology and load balancing on the client?

Comment: com.datastax.oss:java-driver-bom:4.15.0 using DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy. Everything is working fine except when a cassandra server is restarted it is not rebalancing.

Comment: Please provide your driver properties and output of `nodetool status`

Comment: what are you trying to figure out? What do you suspect might be the issue?

Comment: Assumption is that each node is perceiving its location to be in a different data center.

Comment: There are two Cassandra DC with 4 nodes and 1 node. Clients are connected to 4 nodes towards a single DC.

Comment: Can you provide a docker-compose reproduction with a minimal client app?

Comment: Not really except there is real added value which is don't think so. Restart of a container within a docker compose is not really the same as a cassandra restart for example.
I think that's a driver limitation/driver anyway so not much hope to get something fixed easily.